# Virtual PDF printers don't render text background color

Tags: pdf, printing, printer, colors

I noted recently that a Win10 box that I have, stopped printing text background color in virtual PDF printer.
At first I charged it on the virtual PDF printer used (Bullzip), but that same printer works flawlessly on my Win10 laptop.
Looking at the "print preview", colors are solid; printing they disappear and turn to the white/transparent background.

First note: it's not related to a single application, I tried a couple of them (Libreoffice Calc, yED Graph Editor) on both computers, and the behavior is the same, laptop works, desktop doesn't.

I tried a few virtual PDF printers: **Bullzip**/**bioPDF**, **CutePDF**, **PDF24**, **Microsoft PDF**, **Adobe PDF**, all with the same behaviour.
If I print the same page with a totally different format virtual printer, "*Microsoft XPS document writer*", the colors are rendered properly.

I'm suspecting it's something in this system's settings, but I don't remember to have changed anything like that before...
Any advice?

**[Update]**
As I commented, the problem stays in *which* color I choose as a background.
Let's say I use LibreOffice Calc, and put in some background formatting in spreadsheet.
When I select [print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqmz4.png) everything is fine, but when I print it with Bullzip PDF [some colors are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPZ2H.png).
The behaviour is the same with other applications, I used the spreadsheet just to ease to test.

Comment: do you have a test file?

Comment: While I was trying to add files here I tried a few simple cases, and I discovered that only **some** colors **disappear**! I tried it again with yED, and Libreoffice Calc. Creating as an example a spreadsheet with a few different colors in cells background, some "pass through" the PDF, while other don't (still appearing right in the print preview). Again, if I print it to Microsoft XPS printer all colors are correct as in print preview.

Comment: That LibreOffice Calc test-file of yours would still be useful. Provide the original calc-file and the resulting PDF (via a PDF-printer). Also try to export to PDF in LibreOffice itself instead of printing via a PDF printer (File>Export as PDF).

Comment: This is the LibreOffice spreadsheet  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=26570763979336259692
 and this http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07355449779292036167 is the printed PDF, with Bullzip PDF.

Note also that *exporting* directly from LibreOffice to PDF produces a correct document, with all the colors where required. I didn't state it clearly at the beginning, and it was worth clarifying. The problem persists only when I *finalize printing* (from any application) through a virtual device (any but XPS writer).

Comment: is this correct that only one column has colors (opened in MS Office, or is this not supported in MS Office?)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about MS Office issues importing it... Was saved in OpenDocument by LibreOffice 5.04

Comment: @LMS I just downloaded your sample and Bullzip PDF and the Bullzip PDF is correct. Are you sure the given PDF shows missing colors for you. Here is my screenshot of LibreOffice with your file and your Bullzip PDF. https://i.imgur.com/XfOvF2S.png With what viewer are you viewing those PDFs ?? (I use Adobe Reader) Maybe this is a viewer problem instead of a PDF-generation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to thank Rik that with his comment solved my problem!
In fact, it was **somewhat** viewer related and **not** printer related: let me tell it all.

I'm using Adobe Reader 11.0.12, while on laptop I used 11.0.15, so I first verified that same file on laptop, and everything was fine. Then I updated on desktop to 11.0.16, but the issue was still there, uhm! Checking the settings for AR, I found that in *Preferences* -> *Accessibility* -> *Replace document colors* was set: I unticked it, and all the colors returned back to normal!

Maybe I experimented with that for some special document in the past (who knows when?) and I left it set: it had no side effects on other docs, so I never noticed that before.

The defect wasn't in the pen writing, but in my eyes seeing :^)